# If Else statement in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I have a one simple question.But I cannot figure it out since yesterday. I would like to make a 'if else statement' statement in fullcalendar script. If user click on an event which the title is `one`, it will display modalOne. If the user click on other events, it will display modalTwo. I try the below code. It doesnt work. It display modalOne for every event i clicked.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#title").val(calEvent.title);               
            if (calEvent.title = "one") {
                $('#modalOne').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $('#modalTwo').modal('show');
            }
        },
```

Comment: Probably best for you to evaluate the if statement using three equals signs to compare the type as well as value. `if (calEvent.title === "one") {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why your code is always displaying modalOne is because of the below scenario.

```
if (calEvent.title = "one") { // you're assigning title to "one" not checking
    $('#modalOne').modal('show');
}
```

rather try the solution below, also notice how I've used strict equality rather than double equality.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#title").val(calEvent.title);               
            if (calEvent.title === "one") {
                $('#modalOne').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $('#modalTwo').modal('show');
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thank you! but why there is triple equal and not two?

Comment: because strict equality compares both the types and contents of the variable, if you don't use strict equality the javascript interpreter won't check the types but just the contents of the types, in certain scenarios this might lead to unexpected results. also if the solution has solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer as that would mean a lot to me. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps include some links to [information about equality comparisons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)?